# How to add a numpy.array in a numpy.matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, append, addition

I have a matrix, defined by this way:

```
pop = (np.random.randint(3, size=(qtd_individuos, qtd_equipamentos))) + 1
```

and I would like add a new array in this matrix.

```
vetor2 = np.ones((qtd_equipamentos))*2
```

I already tried some things in this way, using np.append, np.vstack, np.stack, np.concatenate, np.add... nothing works... Make it in list is too easy with append. I'm not sure if I'm trying doing it right. The examples that I have found are a little different from this.

```
np.insert(pop, vetor1)
np.stack((pop, vetor2))
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add"? You should show an example of what `pop` and `vetor1` look like before, and what `pop` should look like after.

Comment: If one array is (n,m) and the other is (1,m), `concatenate` is easy.  I bet `concatenate` complained about matching number of dimensions.  Did you try to correct that?

Comment: I'm not sure If I tried it in a correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `vstack` too:

```
np.vstack([pop, vetor2])
```

It's advisable to ensure that types are the same, so you can use for example:

```
vetor2 = np.ones(qtd_equipamentos, dtype=int)*2
```

Your output has `dtype('int32')` which is different from `dtype` without this fix.

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved this way:

```
pop = np.append(pop, [vetor1], axis = 0) # The square brackets are important!
```